# How to run zone-matrix?

Tags: package

I found something that looks like fun:
https://github.com/ober/zone-matrix

A matrix-inspired EMACS screen saver. I need this in my life, but I can't (for the life of me) figure out how to get it to run.

I've placed the files in my `~/.emacs.d/lisp` directory, and appended my init.el to include the load-path and settings per example_user_config.el, but I cannot get it to start by executing 'M-x zone'

I'm running Emacs on MSYS2 (which I believe is the bleeding edge for Windows builds nowadays).

EDIT: Solved. I needed tabbar-mode, which I found here:
https://github.com/dholm/tabbar/blob/master/tabbar.el

Now I see the characters scrolling, it makes me happy!

Comment: Please clarify what you've done.  E.g. I don't know what "appended my init.el" means, and I don't know what you've tried to do to "get it to start" after you run `M-x zone`.

Comment: Modified! Sorry I was unclear; I appended to my init file what was in the example_user_config.el file, and I then tried to execute the package by doing 'M-x zone'

Comment: Please post a stand alone answer rather than mark it solved in the question post. Self-answers are encouraged.

Comment: how did you limit zone to just matrix?

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun tabbar-mode () (lambda (x) (message "%s")))
(add-to-list 'load-path (concat dotfiles-dir "zone"))
(require 'zone-matrix)
(require 'zone-matrix-settings)
(require 'zone-settings)

(setq zone-programs [zone-matrix])
(zone-when-idle 60)
```

This is all you need.
This assumes that you have zone-matrix in ~/.emacs.d/zone as I do.
It also removes the need for the real tabbar-mode.
I cribbed this from somewhere a long while back, and have not found updates to it.